# Chrome 33 shows ugly, blocky, pixelated fonts in Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, fonts, gentoo

After updating to the latest version of Chrome (33) on my Gentoo Linux box, certain sites such as GitHub have started rendering with ugly, pixelated, non-antialiased fonts. Small text is now basically impossible to read.

[image]

Before this, GitHub had looked the same to me on Windows, Linux, and Mac computers. So what has happened here and how can it be fixed?

**EDIT**: Appears to be fixed on the stable release of Chrome 34.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Chromium with the Helvetica font. It is discussed here:

https://forums-web1.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-984870.html?sid=d8fa5b8fc9ae0c83520d1769dc366d58

From that thread, this solution fixed it for me:

- make the following files in some empty directory
- go to chrome://extensions
- check the developer mode box
- Load unpacked extension
- point to the new directory

manifest.json

```
{ 
  "name": "Fix Helvetica", 
  "description": "Fix Helvetica", 
  "version": "0.1", 

  "content_scripts": [ { 
  "css": [ "Custom.css" ], 
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ] 
  } ], 

  "manifest_version": 2 
}
```

Custom.css

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Helvetica'; src: local('Arial')}
```

Comment: This makes the ugliness go away, but makes the page display a different font than before, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I think you'll have to wait until that bug is fixed, or downgrade...

Comment: As of version 33.0.1750.152, this seems to be fixed.

Comment: @PurpleAlien Still happens for me on 34.0.1847.60

Comment: @Michael, could be an issue with your fontconfig (see eselect fontconfig). Wish I had more space here to go into detail, but try to enable 70-no-bitmaps.conf and disable 70-yes-bitmaps.conf for starters.

Comment: @PurpleAlien Yeah, I worked around it with the method from your link; just clarifying that the problem doesn't go away in 33.0.1750.152

Comment: @Michael, well, it did for me. Must be something else then. Only thing I can think of is fontconfig...

Comment: @PurpleAlien I'm still getting it on 33.0.1750.152 as well.

Comment: @Andrew, compare your fontconfig with mine here: http://pastebin.com/uv4Lx7Ag

Comment: @PurpleAlien why do you have all four subpixel rendering schemes on?

Comment: @Andrew, probably a leftover from testing...

Comment: @PurpleAlien Updating to Chrome 34 stable (just released) fixed things without any changes needed to fontconfig.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the issue with Chromium 33-34 and KDE 4.11.5.

[Dehpeh's](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7506124.html#7506124) suggestion solved my issue.

```
eselect fontconfig enable 70-no-bitmaps.conf
```

or if already enabled:

```
eselect fontconfig disable 70-yes-bitmaps.conf
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it for me as well on KDE and Chromium 38.

Answer (score 5):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and had the same problem.
After removing all 70-something configs from /etc/fonts/conf.d and linking
`70-no-bitmaps.conf -> ../conf.avail/70-no-bitmaps.conf` and checking, that the selectfont element in the xml was not commented out and looked like this my fonts render nicely again.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<!-- Reject bitmap fonts -->
  <selectfont>
    <rejectfont>
      <pattern>
        <patelt name="scalable"><bool>false</bool></patelt>
      </pattern>
    </rejectfont>
  </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: thank you worked perfectly. in debian i had to run this after the fonts.conf update `fc-cache -fv`

Comment: I confirm this works in Gentoo, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to disable bitmap fonts by enabling `70-no-bitmaps.conf`, because I'm using them in the xfce4-terminal (i.e. `Fixed` font). So I've found the solution in `29-replace-bitmap-fonts.conf`

`/etc/fonts/conf.avail/29-replace-bitmap-fonts.conf:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <!-- Replace generic bitmap font names by generic font families.
         These font-families will get replaced by other rules and
         default to scaled ones. -->
    <match target="pattern" name="family">
        <test name="family" qual="any">
            <string>Helvetica</string>
        </test>
        <edit mode="assign" name="family">
            <string>Arial</string>
            <string>Liberation Sans</string>
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

And then I've enabled this config:

```
ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/29-replace-bitmap-fonts.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/29-replace-bitmap-fonts.conf
```

For Gentoo users:

```
eselect fontconfig enable 29-replace-bitmap-fonts.conf
```

Comment: btw. this issue still exists in Chromium v. 36

Answer (score 1):

Recently I struggled with the same issue with Chrome on Debian (testing) with XFCE. I just added the following code to `.fonts.conf` file in my home directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign"><const>hintnone</const></edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="hinting"><bool>false</bool></edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

That code basically disables hinting and enables antialiasing. Now everything works like a charm.

([source](http://www.internalpointers.com/post/fixing-ugly-fonts-chrome-chromium-debian-xfce))