# Gentoo Blocky Fonts

Tags: fonts, gentoo

So, I've fresh installed Gentoo with Gnome. Ever since then I've had super blocky fonts like this[image]

I'd appreciate any help on this, or really just a link to anything else because googling gets me no where.

**EDIT** My problem is with Firefox, Atom and anything seeming to use a web releated thing at this point. Image: http://screencloud.net/v/iZIj

Comment: Would you mind to post a full sized picture also? http://imgur.com/ could be used.

Comment: @Nikolay like the same one but on imgur?

Comment: Your problem is in Chrome, right? (if so, you should mention it in the question). did you see this?http://superuser.com/questions/726132/chrome-33-shows-ugly-blocky-pixelated-fonts-in-linux?rq=1

Comment: @RainbowDashDC, yes. Because this picture is too small to see the problem. Also, as meatspace advices include more specifics - do you have problems with a specific program or system wide?

Comment: @Nikolay added image and application specifics

Comment: @RainbowDashDC, thanks. Try installing [gnome-tweak-tool](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/gnome-extra/gnome-tweak-tool) and play with the fonts settings.

Comment: Didn't fix anything, tried changing fonts antialias etc.

Comment: I see. Try to change default font in Firefox settings and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @nikolay Nothing :(

Comment: Hmmm. I use Gentoo too (with XFCE) and never run into this problem. Try to follow instruction given [here](http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/fonts/). It is not about Firefox, but it might help. Try to install more fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, eventually figured this out:

`eselect fontconfig enable 70-no-bitmaps.conf`

or if already enabled:

`eselect fontconfig disable 70-yes-bitmaps.conf`