# Broken fonts on Gentoo

Tags: linux, fonts, gentoo

I'm running Gentoo with KDE and the `infinality` patchset. For the most part, the interface looks just fine.

[image: System settings]

However, in some of the applications the font for Latin characters is ugly. This is a screenshot from Thunderbird of an email which contains both English and Russian text. Notice how Cyrillic characters are rendered beautifully.

[image: Thunderbird]

The Latin font looks like Courier. This is affirmed by the settings dialog of KDiff:

[image]

[image]

My configuration:

```
$ sudo eselect fontconfig list
Available fontconfig .conf files (* is enabled):
  [1]   09-texlive.conf
  [2]   10-autohint.conf
  [3]   10-no-sub-pixel.conf
  [4]   10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf *
  [5]   10-sub-pixel-bgr.conf
  [6]   10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf *
  [7]   10-sub-pixel-vbgr.conf
  [8]   10-sub-pixel-vrgb.conf
  [9]   10-unhinted.conf
  [10]  11-lcdfilter-default.conf *
  [11]  11-lcdfilter-legacy.conf
  [12]  11-lcdfilter-light.conf
  [13]  20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans.conf
  [14]  20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf
  [15]  20-unhint-small-dejavu-serif.conf
  [16]  20-unhint-small-vera.conf *
  [17]  25-ttf-arphic-ukai-render.conf
  [18]  25-ttf-arphic-uming-bitmaps.conf
  [19]  25-ttf-arphic-uming-render.conf
  [20]  25-unhint-nonlatin.conf
  [21]  30-metric-aliases.conf
  [22]  30-urw-aliases.conf *
  [23]  35-ttf-arphic-ukai-aliases.conf
  [24]  35-ttf-arphic-uming-aliases.conf
  [25]  40-nonlatin.conf *
  [26]  41-ttf-arphic-ukai.conf
  [27]  41-ttf-arphic-uming.conf
  [28]  42-luxi-mono.conf *
  [29]  43-wqy-zenhei-sharp.conf
  [30]  44-wqy-zenhei.conf
  [31]  45-latin.conf
  [32]  49-sansserif.conf *
  [33]  50-user.conf *
  [34]  51-local.conf *
  [35]  52-infinality.conf *
  [36]  57-dejavu-sans.conf
  [37]  57-dejavu-sans-mono.conf
  [38]  57-dejavu-serif.conf
  [39]  59-google-droid-sans.conf
  [40]  59-google-droid-sans-mono.conf
  [41]  59-google-droid-serif.conf
  [42]  60-latin.conf
  [43]  60-liberation.conf *
  [44]  61-stix.conf
  [45]  62-croscore-arimo.conf
  [46]  62-croscore-cousine.conf
  [47]  62-croscore-symbolneu.conf
  [48]  62-croscore-tinos.conf
  [49]  64-01-tlwg-kinnari.conf
  [50]  64-02-tlwg-norasi.conf
  [51]  64-11-tlwg-waree.conf
  [52]  64-12-tlwg-loma.conf
  [53]  64-13-tlwg-garuda.conf
  [54]  64-14-tlwg-umpush.conf
  [55]  64-15-laksaman.conf
  [56]  64-21-tlwg-typo.conf
  [57]  64-22-tlwg-typist.conf
  [58]  64-23-tlwg-mono.conf
  [59]  64-ttf-arphic-uming.conf
  [60]  65-fonts-persian.conf *
  [61]  65-khmer.conf
  [62]  65-nonlatin.conf *
  [63]  69-unifont.conf *
  [64]  70-no-bitmaps.conf
  [65]  70-yes-bitmaps.conf
  [66]  75-ttf-arphic-ukai-select.conf
  [67]  80-delicious.conf *
  [68]  89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf
  [69]  89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf
  [70]  89-tlwg-laksaman-synthetic.conf
  [71]  89-tlwg-loma-synthetic.conf
  [72]  89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf
  [73]  89-tlwg-waree-synthetic.conf
  [74]  90-synthetic.conf *
  [75]  90-ttf-arphic-ukai-embolden.conf
  [76]  90-ttf-arphic-uming-embolden.conf
  [77]  99pdftoopvp.conf

$ sudo eselect infinality list
Available styles:
  [1]   debug
  [2]   infinality
  [3]   linux
  [4]   nyx
  [5]   osx
  [6]   osx2
  [7]   win7 *
  [8]   win98
  [9]   winxp

$ sudo eselect lcdfilter list
Available styles:
  [1]   custom
  [2]   default
  [3]   infinality
  [4]   infinality-classic
  [5]   infinality-nudge
  [6]   infinality-push
  [7]   infinality-sharpened
  [8]   infinality-shove
  [9]   linux
  [10]  nyx
  [11]  osx
  [12]  ubuntu
  [13]  vanilla
  [14]  windows-7 *
  [15]  windows-7-light
  [16]  windows-xp
  [17]  windows-xp-light
```

I guess my problem is related to [Gentoo Blocky Fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/873214/gentoo-blocky-fonts). The "ugly" font looks the same.